# JavaScript Model Form Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, backbone.js

I am using BackboneJS MVC pattern and have a form with 2 fields which the user can select.

I call changeAction whenever there is any change in selection by the user (to call validation);

```
changeAction: function (event) {
    var self = this;
    var target = event.target;

    target.value = $.trim(target.value);
    change[target.name] = target.value;
    this.model.set(change);

    var check = self.model.validateItem(target.id);
    if (check.isValid === false) {
        self.addValidationError(target.id, check.message);
    } else {
        self.removeValidationError(target.id);
    }
}
```

My validation is defined in the Model as below;

```
this.validators.myDropDownField = function(value) {
    return !_.isUndefined(value) && !_.isNull(value) && $.trim(value).length > 0 ? {
        isValid: true
    } : {
        isValid: false,
        message: "Select dropdown field"
    };
};

validateItem: function(key) {
    var result = (this.validators[key]) ? this.validators[key](this.get(key)) : {
        isValid: true
    };
    return result;
}
```

Now my question is I do not want to do anything to the Model in changeAction.
But if I remove the line `this.model.set(change)` in `changeAction()`

the validation does not work correctly. I do not get the value in the function

> this.validators.myDropDownField

How do I handle this ?

Comment: Are you have target.id and target.name is same key name? And if you do not want use model.set, how you explain check not changed value in model validators?

Comment: You have two options:
1.) Create a replica of the model(ViewModel/DataModel) and perform the validation on it.
2.) Use Backbone validation, which makes everything a lot easier
http://thedersen.com/projects/backbone-validation/

Comment: this.model.set(userData, {validate:false});
  set validate false when you set value and 
  if (this.model.isValid(true)){

  } use http://thedersen.com/projects/backbone-validation/